# Client side confirmation message on Page layout

Tags: custom-button, validation, page-layout, validation-rule, publisher-action

I am new to Salesforce and couldn't find any answer by direct search. So excuse me if this sounds very trivial. I'm building a functionality where on save (update) of an event page, some action will performed If event status field value is "XYZ". Before performing this action, I'd like to show an Message to users and seek confirmation to proceed.

I know we can do that by adding client side validation and by showing an confirmation pop-up using visualforce page but Can we achieve that without designing a page for this. Also, I'm looking for a solution which is compatible with Salesforce 1 App, which is used by my application users.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bra7AAC is what you'd be looking for. Make sure you vote on the idea.